# How to calculate autocovariance matrix of data in the form of a matrix that is simulated from vector MA(1) process in R

Tags: r

I have simulated data from a VARMA process using "MTS" package. But I not able to find its autocovariance matrix. 
Note: "VARMAcov" in MTS package is not providing any help.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?